# Replcae "&g" with "&gt;" using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace some character from my string using regex.

For Ex: replace `&g` by `&gt;`.

How can i do it using Regex?

Thanks in advance,
Sagar

Comment: have u tried/search anything so far??

Comment: Yes i have tried , with regex patern "\b&g\b".... I am doing like this Regex.Replace("this is te&gst", "\b&g\b", "&gt;");

Comment: Why would you use regex when your search string is a simple static piece of text?

Comment: You probably misunderstand the meaning of `\b`, it disallows adjacent alphabetics. It would match on "te&g st" but clearly that is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Replace(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) from [System.Text.RegularExpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx):

```
string sResult = Regex.Replace(sText, "&g", "&gt;");
```

or [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx#Y0):

```
string sResult = sText.Replace("&g", "&gt;");
```

Also see [example 1](http://ideone.com/DCwpi) and [example 2](http://ideone.com/0zVl9).